# Resource Allocation Manager

Tags: java

I am trying to work on a Resource Allocation Manager in Java where I have the following input:

Input 1, will be an order which will be a key value pair of item and quantity. Something like:

```
{ item1: 5, item2: 10, item3: 5 }
```

Input 1, will be q list of places which have inventory. Something like:

```
{ place1: { item1: 20, item2: 5, item3: 0 }, place2: { item2: 2, item3: 20 } }
```

I am working on something that can get me the best possible way of resource allocation from the inventory place. I have been brainstorming and got the following data structure, but still feel it may not help me for the best solution. Can someone suggest what I may be missing and what is the best way to solve this one?

Skeleton code:

```
public static class Order {
    List<Item> items;
}

public static class Item {
    String itemName;
    int itemCount;
}

public static class Resource {
    String name;
    Order inventory;
}
```

Here I am iterating over the Resource list and checking if Inventory is present. However, I feel this may not be a good way to solve this problem. Can someone pls suggest what can be a good and optimal way to solve this in Java?

Comment: Sometimes data structures that reflect the data being inputted are the best option. If you parse your input into a hashmap of strings and intergers it might be easier... but in reality the best way of testing this is just to do testing. Create a script to generate some data, load it into your program somehow and do some run time analysis.

Comment: with `Resource Allocation Manager` you mean some sort of `cache` ?